# Why does the QueuePerformanceCounter behave odd?

Tags: c#, time, performancecounter

Good day fellow developers,

I'm trying to create a Timing class in C# which can output the amount of time it takes to execute specific lines code. Here is the class that I developed so far (it is using the QueryPerformanceCounter):

```
class Timing
{
    private long start;
    private long stop;
    private long frequency;
    Decimal multiplier = new Decimal(1.0e9);

    // Importing important DLL's that will be used
    [DllImport("KERNEL32")]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(out long lpPerformanceCount);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(out long lpFrequency);

    // Timing constructor
    public Timing()
    {
        if (QueryPerformanceFrequency(out frequency) == false)
        {
            // Frequency not supported
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    // Method for starting the counter
    public void Start()
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(out start);
    }

    // Method for stopping the counter
    public void Stop()
    {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(out stop);
    }

    // Returns the average time between iterations in nanoseconds
    public double Duration(int iterations)
    {
        return ((((double)(stop - start) * (double)multiplier) / (double)frequency) / iterations);
    }

    // Get the elapsed time between the start and the stop function in nanoseconds
    public double getElapsedTime()
    {
        return (((double)(stop - start) * (double)multiplier) / (double)frequency);
    }
}
```

I wanted to perform a test to see if my Timing class would print out the same amount of time when executing the same line of code five times in a row:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        runCollectionTest(1000);
        runCollectionTest(1000);
        runCollectionTest(1000);
        runCollectionTest(1000);
        runCollectionTest(1000);

        while (true) ;
}

public static void runCollectionTest(int iterations)
{
        Timing timer = new Timing();
        timer.Start();

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: " + timer.getElapsedTime() / 1000000 + " milliseconds");
}
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
Time elapsed: 0,24631157341192 milliseconds
Time elapsed: 0,0486376114202896 milliseconds
Time elapsed: 0,0620241099763327 milliseconds
Time elapsed: 0,0589005936465893 milliseconds
Time elapsed: 0,088350890469884 milliseconds
```

I have no idea how the first time elapse and the second one can differ that much compared to the other results.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use the [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) class, which wraps around `QueryPerformanceCounter` for systems that support it (which is nearly all of them these days? Using QPC correctly has some caveats that `Stopwatch` has already solved.

Comment: As to your general question: initial runs of managed code tend to be slower because the JIT compiler hasn't compiled everything yet and initial memory/resource allocations haven't been done yet. This is why benchmarks usually discard the first run (unless they specifically aim to investigate start-up performance).